# PayPal callback API NO_SHIPPING_OPTION_DETAILS ignored

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, express-checkout

I'm using the callback API to prevent someone selecting a non-UK shipping address. I've supplied a callback url, I've set CALLBACKVERSION to 61.0.

When I go into the sandbox and choose an address I know the callback page is being called as I've added code to email me the values submitted to it and the value returned to PayPal. For anything with a SHIPTOCOUNTRY that isn't GB the response is

```
METHOD=CallbackResponse&NO_SHIPPING_OPTION_DETAILS=1
```

I've also tried setting a fuller response in case it doesn't like some required field to be missing

```
METHOD=CallbackResponse&CURRENCYCODE=GBP&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME0=Standard&L_SHIPPINGALABEL0=Standard&L_SHIPPINGAMOUNT0=2.95&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT0=true&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME1=Express&L_SHIPPINGALABEL1=Express&L_SHIPPINGAMOUNT1=5.95&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT1=false&NO_SHIPPING_OPTION_DETAILS=1
```

But it's still allowing non-UK addresses and just using the shipping options set during the initial set up request.

Any suggestions on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Do you have a transaction ID I can look up for a payment that completed with "NO_SHIPPING_OPTION_DETAILS=1" set?

Comment: Hi Patrick, I just ran a test and captured the following PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID => 6FN26261X1789110E Is that the value you are looking for? Many thanks for your assistance.

Comment: The buyer account used in the transaction (pboxppbuyer) is a UK sandbox personal account. It doesn't have any other registered addresses and a different address wasn't provided in the SetExpressCheckout call that I can see.

Comment: Hi Patrick, I just logged into the sandbox for the pboxppbuyer account and checked the transaction I made on Friday, it has a different transaction ID to the one I saw on the response, the new one is ID82598631EJ719121H, my apologies if I gave the wrong value yesterday. The accepted postal address in the transaction details on the sandbox is one in the United States.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After opening a ticket as suggested by PayPal_Patrick the problem was that I was adding the callbackversion in the wrong place. The full response to reject a shipping address on callback is:

METHOD=CallbackResponse&NO_SHIPPING_OPTION_DETAILS=1&CALLBACKVERSION=61

Comment: I've this response and it still doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are different transaction ID's for Buyer and Seller accounts.

I think this might be an issue caused by the country associated with the buyer account being used. I'm going to reach out to the product team for Express Checkout and see if it is intended functionality or not - I don't believe it would be.

If you want to stay updated on the issue I would recommend creating a ticket to PayPal.com/mts, give me the ticket number, I'll grab it and keep you involved.

Comment: Hi Patrick, I've submitted a support ticket as you suggested, the ticket is #130618-000020. Many thanks again.